# How to solve the matplotlib? installation error?

Tags: python

I am using IDLE for Python Programming. I happen to a problem. The problem is shown as follows:
[image]

But the matplotlib is installed successfully, please see the picture below:
[image]

I give a full view of the error. please see the figure below:
[image]
Can anyone tell me how to solve the installation problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: This is not an IDLE installation error, as claimed in the title.  I suspect that it is a matplotlib installation error.  The failure is the attempt to import .../matplotlib/_path.?? from .../matplotlib/path.py.  By convention, _path.?? should be a compiled C file.  I expect that the extension should be .dll.  The fact that pip thinks that matplotlib is installed does not mean that it is installed correctly.  See if _path.?? exists.  Then try importing without IDLE involved.  In command prompt, try, for instance, `python -m matplotlib._path` or `python -c "import matplotlib._path"`.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, when I type python -m matplotlib._path, it still shows error, almost the same as the previous errors. What should I do ?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, can you tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, I edit the question, I give a full view of the error information,Please take a look at it! Thank you so much!

Comment: A different error message.  The  English original is "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application".  Learn to use search bars.  Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python and enter `WinError 193` in the search bar.  See of any of the answers help you.  If not, search the web for `python WinError 193`.   Aside from this, you seem to be using a Chinese version of Windows.  Perhaps this is an issue for matplotlib.